# How to unit test the columns names are valid for a function that reads data with `pandas.read_sql()`?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, unit-testing, read-sql

I have a function to read data from a MySQL database:

```
def example(mysql_engine) -> DataFrame:
    query = """SELECT col_1 FROM xxx.xxx"""
    df = pandas.read_sql(query, mysql_engine)

    return df
```

`mysql_engine` is returned by another function, now I want to write unit tests to validate the column name `col_1` and datatype in `df`, is there an example I can follow? Do I need to set up a real database engine in unit test?

Comment: Assert that the df columns are ['id', 'blah', 'foo', 'bar'] or `df.dtypes` matches what you expect?

Comment: both, so one test case is to validate `col_1` is in `df`, another test case is to validate the dtypes of `col_1` is `int64`(for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert col_1 in df.columns` for the unit tests.

For the Database engine, you can use a mock object. You can check [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) from the standard library.

Comment: but how should I get the `df` in the unit test? I'm thinking if I define a `dummy_df = {'col_1': ['123456', '789456']}` - assuming this is the dataframe that is returned from `read_sql`, then use `mock_read_sql.return_value = dummy_df` then `self.assertTrue('col_1' in dummy_df.columns)`, but something doesn't feel right about this approach... I don't know how to get `df` so that I can use `assertTrue('col_1' in df.columns)` instead of `assertTrue('col_1' in dummy_df.columns)`

Comment: @Cecilia You actually want to unit test the function which the `df` is the output of it. You can pass a mock engine where mock.return_value equals the result you want from the DB. Then you would call your function and assert the output `df`

Comment: ` Then you would call your function and assert the output df` - if I call the function, does that mean I have to query against the real database? Don't think I want to do that, if I don't query against the real db with the query, unit test will complain... Is there an example?